# Alt + Enter: how to open Property Pages instead of Properties?

Tags: visual-studio

Actual behavior: Alt + Enter leads to opening Properties:

[image]

Expected behavior: Alt + Enter leads to opening Property Pages:

[image]

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `Options => Keyboard` and assign `Alt + Enter` to `View.PropertyPages`:

[image]